Python evaluation of expression
Python yields different answers
>>> 0 < 0 == 0
False

>>> (0 < 0) == 0
True

>>> 0 < (0 == 0)
True

is this a bug?
Python 3.11.10 (main, Sep  7 2024, 18:35:41) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.


No, this not a bug. Python comparison operators can be chained. 0 < 0 == 0 means 0 < 0 and 0 == 0, not (0 < 0) == 0 or 0 < (0 == 0).

ah, of course, thx

@MrJ careful, in and is are both comparison operators, and they are chained just like >, < etc
